# XPath in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

Our website has different code on mobile and desktop versions. We want to check HTML attributes through XPath (ImportlXML function). But as you can understand, sometimes they're different for different devices. And Google Sheets provides only data for desktop.

So, question is how I can see results of performing ImportlXML function (through XPath) for mobile using only Google Sheets?

Also, please, tell me query in Google Sheets, which give me all attributes of, for example, `<a>` tag.

P. S. Thanks a lot for helping me out with this problems.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML is able to access the static source code of your web page. In other words, if you dinamically build the DOM of your web page, it can't be accessed by IMPORTXML.